# Convert mysql_fetch_assoc to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm struggling to securely convert the below into PDO. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

```
function getSlug($param)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug = '$param'") OR die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the PDO doc?

Comment: First you need to `prepare` the query.Then `execute` it using PARAMS.Then you can return result using `PDO:FETCH_ASSOC` Constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDO CONNECTION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

**Connections and Connection management ¶**

> Connections are established by creating instances of the PDO base
>   class. It doesn't matter which driver you want to use; you always use
>   the PDO class name. The constructor accepts parameters for specifying
>   the database source (known as the DSN) and optionally for the username
>   and password (if any).

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);  <<== This is the PDO DATABASE OBJECT 

function getSlug($param)
{
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug = ?"); <<== First you need to prepare it
$sth->execute(array($param)); <<== Then execute it using params 
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); <<== Then USe PDO Constant to get Associative array
return $result; <<<== Then return it 

}
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in line 6".

Comment: Edited.I missed the `:` in `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: Thanks for the update but now I get another error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on line 5"

Comment: For that you need to create to create a PDO Object.Wait.I'll update complete guide

Comment: Make it answer if it helped :)

Comment: I will. Hopefully you can answer my next question. The code above is in functions.php. Then in another file I have this: `<?php
 include('functions.php');
 $param = $_GET['param'];
 $slug = getSlug($_GET['param']); ?>`
But this returns the same 'non'object' error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44970/discussion-between-aphextwig-and-samitha)